# java - nullpointer exception

Tags: java

Guys i need some help here , im getting this error here at the  code snippet below. 
here's the stack trace. i have a feeling that somebody's gonna say not much effort on my part. its ok i agree , give me a suggestion what should i do more and ill do it just that i've got a little stuck and not moving ahead so thought of posting it here.

i think i'm having a problem because i'm using a code that was used for writing an excel file when the size of content to write to excel was pre - known . what i actually need is some way to write to excel when the length of rows and collumns may vary .

```
Length of Array:2000
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.temp2.cod2.WriteToExcel.setExcel(WriteToExcel.java:149) >> line 149 is last line of the code snippet below i.e. byte buf[] = s.getBytes();
```

here the code snippet

```
String data[][] = new String [2000][5];

System.out.println("Length of Array:"+data.length);

for(int j=0;j<colN.length;j++){
    Label myLabel1=new Label(j,1,colVal[j]);
    wst.addCell(myLabel1);
}

for(int i=2;i<=data.length+1;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<colN.length;j++)
    {
            // Encrypt
            encrypter.encrypt(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\Encrypted.txt"),new FileOutputStream("temp.txt"));
            // Decrypt

            ByteArrayOutputStream f = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            String s = data[i-2][j];
            byte buf[] = s.getBytes();
```

Comment: Code looks better with spaces instead of tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reference to `s` in `s.getBytes` is probably null. So that means what is getting executed is something like

```
byte buf[] = null.getBytes();
```

Which doesn't make much sense. So what you want to do to correct this might be something like this

```
String s = data[i-2][j];
byte buf[];
if (s != null) 
    buf = s.getBytes();
else
   buf = //What do you want the default behavior to be? maybe "".getBytes()?
```

Comment: Don't expect s to be not null with the actual code. BTW, avoiding using brackets is really not a good idea, even for a single line.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously `data[i-2][j]` is null. You are not setting it anywhere, so it is null.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `data[i-2][j]` is `null`. Is it supposed to be non `null`? Check how you are initializing it then because, currently, you're just declaring `data[][]` to be a `String[2000][5]` array, you're not initializing its content. So it's filled with nulls.

Answer (score 1):

At what point do you initialize the data[][] array?

```
String data[][] = new String [2000][5];
```

allocates the space but it appears that you never put any Strings in the array.

Also I feel I should point out that string.getBytes() is not character-encoding safe.  You should always specify the character encoding, such as UTF-8 or UTF-16.  Remember, the characters in the string are not equivalent to bytes; getBytes() transforms the data.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize the contents of the array. You will need to loop over the array and assign strings to the elements:

```
String[][] data = new String[2000][5];

for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        data[i][j] = new String(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey rover, You have declared your array of array as

```
String data[][] = new String [2000][5];
```

and you are accessing the location [2000]. In the above array your index should always be less that 2000.